# How to activate scroll bar in LibreOffice Writer on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, libreoffice, configuration

I have noticed that on the Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 version of LibreOffice Writer that there is no scroll bar at the side no matter how long a document is, this can get rather annoying. Is this a bug or is there some way of 'activating' it that I just haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though in previous versions doing as the other answers said would have worked (going `View > Scrollbars > Vertical Scroll bar`), in the version in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 there is a bug meaning that whatever one does the scroll bars do not show. Remove the `libreoffice-gtk3` as a temporary workaround:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk3
```

This bug only seems to affect GTK 3.20. So users not using GNOME 3.20 will not be affected by this issue.

---

Related bug: [LP #1592572](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1592572)

Comment: I am using 16.04, LibreOffice 5, kernel 4.5, and the option to show/hide scrollbars works fine for me.

Comment: @PSmith: This issue only affects those running GNOME 3.20, what version of GNOME are you running? I assume 3.18 as that is the version coming by default with all the Ubuntu flavours using it even if not as a DE.

Comment: Well my friend, you are correct.. I missed that part about 3.2~; my mistake. I also just learned about `gnome-shell --version` a moment ago :D

Answer (score 3):

Go to **View** > **Scrollbars** and select **Vertical Scrollbar**.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to use comment for this, but I don't care. I prefer your answer to mine and you got there first too. :) Great job!

Comment: I could have sworn I typed that period... :D heh thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks, @proprocastinator! Awesome username btw.. haha I respect that. And yeah just cool to be in the community where more than one person hurried to help another one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To get the scroll bars back click the "View" menu at the top of the program, click "Scrollbars" and tick then "Vertical Scroll bar".